# Possible to cascade HP StorageWorks P4300 G2?

Tags: raid, hardware, hp, storage-area-network, fibre-channel

From my understanding HP StorageWorks P4300 G2 is intended to be multiplexed over 1Gb ethernet when used as a SAN, where half of them should be in a remote location.

If all 4 are next to each other, would it then be possible to Fibre Channel cascade them and  have a RAID 6 across the nodes?

If, which Fibre Channel adapters should I get for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if all 4 are next to each other, would it then be possible to Fibre
>   Channel cascade them and have a RAID 6 across the nodes?

No, they're not disk shelves, they're full servers with their own CPUs, memory, DAS disks - it's the software that clusters them into pairs for resilience - so no you can't just FC-connect them all together. Oh and 'multiplex' isn't the right term, it's 'remote replication' or similar.

Comment: Ok, so the magic happens in the HP software. Are the nodes so standard  that Linux could be installed on them?

Comment: Yes absolutely - obviously that'll wipe and break their current data and functionality but you could put something like glusterfs on them and perhaps achieve something close to what you want.